# Acumular notificaciones en la barra de estado

Tags: android, notificaciones

Tengo un problema, que mi app envía por ejemplo

> 2 notificaciones al mismo tiempo

de dos clases que extienden de un servicio, pero solo se queda con la ultima notificación, no las acumula para ver las dos, deseo acumular todas las notificaciones en la barra y que el usuario la deba eliminar.

**La primera clase que extiende de un servicio**

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e(TAG2, "Timer cancelado");
        super.onDestroy();


        int icono = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =(NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent i=new Intent(ServicioTimer2.this, tiempo_carro2.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ServicioTimer2.this, 0, i, 0);

        mBuilder =new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(icono)
                .setContentTitle("Carro 2")
                .setContentText("Tiempo de carro 2 terminado!")
                .setVibrate(new long[] {100, 250, 100, 500})
                .setAutoCancel(false);

        mNotifyMgr.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

    }
```

**La segunda clase es el mismo código anterior solo cambian el mensaje.**

Comment: Hola, hace tiempo no te veía por aquí, te sugiero revisar en el sitio, puedes ser que lo deseado ya se haya respondido anteriormente, saludos!

Comment: @Jorgesys Hola Jaja revisare gracias !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El metodo [`NotificationManager#notify()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(int,%20android.app.Notification)) recibe un `int` que es el id de la notificacion. Debes de especificarle un id diferente para cada notificacion que vas a mostrar en el metodo `mNotifyMgr.notify(1, mBuilder.build());` y el sistema las creara de manera independiente.

Por ejemplo:

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e(TAG2, "Timer cancelado");
        super.onDestroy();


        int icono = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =(NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent i=new Intent(ServicioTimer2.this, tiempo_carro2.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ServicioTimer2.this, 0, i, 0);

        mBuilder =new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(icono)
                .setContentTitle("Carro 2")
                .setContentText("Tiempo de carro 2 terminado!")
                .setVibrate(new long[] {100, 250, 100, 500})
                .setAutoCancel(false);

        Random r = new Random(); // id random para notificacion
       int randomNo = r.nextInt(1000+1);
      mNotifyMgr.notify(randomNo, mBuilder.build());

    }
```

Comment: Gracias, ha funcionado ! :D